# Caching downloaded dependencies with Docker

Tags: maven, docker

I'm building a Docker image to build and run tests on Java application trying to allow Docker to cache downloaded dependencies the same way that works with Ruby and Node.js applications with the following `Dockerfile`

```
FROM maven:latest
ENV APP_DIR=/app
RUN mkdir -p $APP_DIR
WORKDIR $APP_DIR
COPY pom.xml $APP_DIR
RUN mvn dependency:resolve
COPY . $APP_DIR
CMD mvn test
```

But when a image is run, `mvn test` still downloads dependencies, any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: The Maven cache `$HOME/.m2/repository` is located inside the docker container and not mapped to a volume outside the container...

Comment: Thanks. I swtiched `openjdk` container as the base

Comment: That will not really change a thing cause the Maven cache is not mounted outside the container...

Comment: I'm ok with dependencies being downloaded once, they aren't downloaded on subsequent builds if `pom.xml` stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can force maven not to download any artificates by running it in offline mode. However, you need first to have all dependencies locally available.

```
...
COPY pom.xml $APP_DIR
RUN mvn -Dmaven.repo.local=./maven-repo test
COPY . $APP_DIR
CMD mvn -Dmaven.repo.local=./maven-repo test -o
```

Comment: Which will result in not able being to build something..cause initially you need to download artfacts...after the first time you can try that...